# Converting NSDictionary to CFDictionary in VideoToolbox

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, video-toolbox, cfdictionary

What's the difference between

```
const void *keys[] = { kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey };
OSStatus pixelFormatType = kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA;
CFNumberRef pixelFormatTypeRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &pixelFormatType);
const void *values[] = { pixelFormatTypeRef };
CFDictionaryRef destinationImageBufferAttrs = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
```

and

```
CFDictionaryRef destinationImageBufferAttrs = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(@{(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:@(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)});
```

?

I am getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error if I use the second one. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code sample, the reference stored into `destinationImageBufferAttrs` is owned and must be later released using `CFRelease` (or transferred to ARC control).

In the second code sample, the reference stored into `destinationImageBufferAttrs` is under ARC control and ARC can free it immediately after the assignment as there are no longer ARC-owned references to it.

Change `__bridge` to `__bridge_retained` to transfer ownership from ARC to your own code, you will then be responsible for calling `CFRelease` for the object.

Comment: Far better answer than mine! Thanks. But it is `__bridge_retained`, not `__bridge_retain`. I'll edit the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `@{}` literal was not retained after putting into the `CFDictionaryRef` when I wanted to access again. So below code will work instead:

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:@(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)}; // "dic" reference will retain the nsdic created with @ literal
CFDictionaryRef destinationImageBufferAttrs = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dic;
```